# Write a function which return any number of hexadecimal colors in an array

Tags: arrays, colors, hex

I stack, I don't know how to create arrays of hexadecimal colors. If You know, please share.

```
function concatArray(n){
let arr = []
let hashtag = '#'
let semicolon = ','
let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)
let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)
let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
  arr.push(hashtag,r,g,b,semicolon)
  }
   console.log(arr.join(''))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let arrayOfHexaColors = () => {
  let allHexCodes = '123456789abcdef';
  let loopCount = parseInt(Math.random() * 50);
  let hexColorArr = [];
  
  for(let x=1; x<=loopCount; x++) {
     let hexChars = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        hexChars.push(allHexCodes[parseInt(Math.random() * allHexCodes.length) - 1]);
     }
     hexColorArr.push('#' + hexChars.join(''));
  }
  return hexColorArr;
} 
console.log(arrayOfHexaColors());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayOfhexaColors(){
    let alph = 'abcdef123456789'
    
    let randomloop = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
    let hexcar = [];
    for(let i =0 ;i<randomloop;i++){
        let hash = '#'
        for(let j =0;j<6;j++){
            hash+=alph[Math.floor(Math.random()*alph.length)]
        }
        hexcar.push(hash)
    }
    console.log(hexcar);
}

arrayOfhexaColors()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).